# The pwntools module is not applied

Tags: python, pwntools

Install the App

Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.

Run in Terminal app: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null

and press enter/return key.

Wait for the command to finish.
Run:
brew install pwntools
Done! You can now use pwntools.

**[I use this link](http://macappstore.org/pwntools/)**
but it is not work...

```
❯ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> from pwn import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pwn
```

Comment: no module named pwn is pretty explicit.

Comment: Did you try importing `pwntools` instead, or checking the list of your installed modules?

Comment: yes.. not work too..

Answer (score 1):

python2:

```py
python -m pip install pwntools
```

python3:

```py
python3 -m pip install pwntools
```